# How does allow-control-allow-origin plugin works

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I'm just learning ajax and cors something and now I wonder how does chrome plugin 'allow-control-allow-origin' works.

When I was trying to do a normal ajax request, the console showed the error 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested' which presented that the request was not sent from the same domain.

But when I enable the chrome plugin 'allow-control-allow-origin' the ajax respone was displayed normally.

The cors principle is used to make the server not allow to give the request to some domain which not on the trust list. But how could a plugin do the same thing which need to be done on the server side.

Comment: You're mistaken, the CORS principle is used by **the browser** to prevent client scripts from having access to the response unless it's from the same domain or explicitly allowed by the server. The server still sends the response, the browser plugin simply changes how the browser behaves.

Comment: Like said above it is just how the browser handles it.
I did a small writeup about the CORS subject here and different approaches to it:
https://gist.github.com/jesperorb/6ca596217c8dfba237744966c2b5ab1e

Answer (score 0):

Append in server response in header field,Below code helps you for resolving the issue,i am using below code in java.You can use any other language also.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin");
```